# Unable to verify/create output bucket when using lambda to query Athena and output to different aws account s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I have 2 accounts A and B, my Athena data is in account A and I want to create a lambda to run the Athena query in account A and put the result to an S3 bucket in account B. I have done following but got 'Unable to verify/create output bucket' error in lambda. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

1. In account A, I created an IAM role that has all s3 and athena access, and also the cross account access policy as follow.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:CreateBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::accountB-s3-name/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::accountB-s3-name"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

2. Use IAM role in step A to create Lambda in account A, Lambda script in python:

```
import time
import boto3
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
 
 
query = "select 'EU' as region \
        , year \
        , month \
        , day \
        , count(*) as total \
        FROM table_name\
        group by 1,2,3,4"

DATABASE = 'database_name'
output='s3://accountB-s3-name/test'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('athena')
    # Execution
    response = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=query,
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': DATABASE
        },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': output,
        }
    )
    return response
```

3. In account B S3 bucket policy, I added permissions as follow:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::accountA:role/lambda-role-in-account-A",
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::accountB-s3-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::accountB-s3-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run the Athena query in the account where you want the output to go.  So setup permissions from Athena in Account B to query Account A and setup the output to be the local bucket in Account B.

Comment: In my account B, I also have the same athena table with same database name and table name. Therefore, I can not keep the Lambda script the same and need to specify the table location (account A), I am wondering what's the code for that?